# Mudar o menu do bootstrap de acordo com a largura da pagina

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap-3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web  e coloquei na minha aplicação o menu do bootstrap gostaria que quando a aplicação chegar a largura maxima de  `max-width: 770px` o menu ficasse igual ao menu que fica na largura normal da pagina.

Menu na largura normal da pagina

UPDATE

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Menu na largura maxima de `770px`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
@media (max-width: 770px) {

body{

    background-color: yellow;
}


.navbar-header{
    display: none;
}

.nav .navbar-nav{

    display: inline;
}



 }
```

```html
<div class="body-wrap" >

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="azul">
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" ></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <div class="conteudo"><li><a href="#">Pagina Principal</a></li></div> 
          <div class="conteudo"> <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li></div>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <div class="conteudo"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Produtos <b class="caret"></b></a></div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>
             <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bermudas</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>




    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tirar este treicho do código:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Caso você não queira utilizar o mobile, se for utilizar, mantem e edita o css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .navbar-header{
         ...
    }
}
```

Aconcelho dar uma olhada neste [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) onde você pode trabalhar com diversos tipo de `@media`.

Comment: e se eu quiser usar o mobile somente em uma resolução de 990px como faço ? essa é minha duvida

Comment: Jonathan atualizei a pergunta e coloquei meu CSS, mas mesmo assim ao aplicar a @media screean max-width: 770px o .nav .navbar-nav não apareceu